# Problems with borders of the td

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey stackoverflow people, i need help with my script. Ive created script which on dbl click lets to change date. And ive added borders for that td so that person could see the which date he is changing here is the picture:

[image]

But when i ain't closing it with button but instead trying to change other date, the blue borders are staying. If i close normaly i made them dissapear. How can i fix it? Here is the picture how it looks like and the code bellow:

[image]

On double click i made javascript function:

```
document.getElementById(cellId).style.border = "2px solid #0000FF";
```

If i press Uždaryti(Close) then it works like:

```
document.getElementById(cellId).style.border = 'none';
```

So i repeat, how can i make the borders disapear if im trying to change other date instead of closing it with button?

Comment: Most likely you just need to reset the css on focus change or something. But without more of your js code, it'll be hard to give you a correct answer.

Comment: on doubleclick you could select all the other cells by classname, make the border 'none' and then style the one selected as you did. Other (better, but more code) option is to save the previous selected into a var, and 'unselect' it when you select the new one.

Comment: Or is it possible to somehow create td:active? for this `<td id="start_'.$currentTasken.'" nowrap="nowrap" align="center" ondblclick="mouseCords(event);editCellValue(this)" style="' . $style . '; border: none;" title="'.$AppUI->_('Double click to edit date').'">` If i could make it then it would vanish

Comment: I suggest you to write a CSS class for this border style. Then bind the class dynamically as you do by setting style.border. But before do that you can get the all the existing cells with your class by getElementsByClassName() and unset their class. Then apply the class to clicked one.

Comment: Ive made all `border: none;` but still. When iam trying to change date without closing  before, borders stay blu.